# What can be the algorithm to find all disjoint sets from a set of sets?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, set

I have 'n' sets (n<10). Each set may have lets say, 1000 elements. I want to find all the disjoint sets for these sets. Say, for eg, I have sets

```
A = {2,5,6,7}, B = {5,1} and C = {5,7}.
```

Then the output would be `{{5}, {2,6}, {1}, {7}}`. What can be the algorithm for this? I thought about finding pairwise disjoint sets and then using these new (disjoint)sets to again find disjoint sets from the sets which are left. But this will not scale well. Hope this helps: [Diagram Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Tbu81vajWyVnk4NzVjUmtpaDA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you please say a few words about the properties of the output, or better what you do to obtain it? For example, why is {2} and {6} not included?

Comment: @davidhigh Consider it like this: You have 2 sets A and B. The disjoint sets would be A-B, A intersection B, and B-A. Hope this helps: https://doc-0c-a4-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/i4h2cehd386i3qiqgfp2t1a9r0fu5o6m/qhu2v38hp0h1pdvvehj9vgmdsctujsbt/1452340800000/02075453514295040169/02075453514295040169/0BzbXcZ2xK6JrZ1NiblVXeGpMYms?h=07006165945320890235&nonce=89dl1pkjorq58&user=02075453514295040169&hash=7is7r402mkd2ag6amo4l23vn1bp5cqfd

Comment: Cannot connect to your link :/. A solution could be to consider your problem as a double entry map: row would be element and column sets. I will try to write a draft.

Comment: @88877 Have fixed the link in the description. Can you elaborate your solution?

Comment: As I was commenting on a now-deleted answer, this is a purely algorithmic question. It doesn’t belong to a particular programming language, and doesn’t mention one. So @Eric Aya, could you explain your motivation for reverting my tag edit? Specifically: why is the [c++] tag relevant, and why [disjoint-sets] isn’t?

Comment: @Maëlan "this is a purely algorithmic question" This is your opinion. What I see is someone knowing C++ asking about this algo - probably to implement it. Anyway, we're not here to guess: there's a language tag (you say it "doesn’t mention" a language, but it does, the tag does it), so it's not a code-agnostic question. Your edits should not deviate from OP's intentions. In other words: please let it be. :)

Comment: @Maëlan And I have no opinion about [disjoint-sets]. It's just that I rolled back your edit so the question got back to its previous state. Feel free to *add* the tag if you think it's helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider your problem as a boolean two entry map, elements being the rows, sets being the columns and the boolean is the answer of the question is the element included in the set. For instance your example would be:

```
t A B C
2 1 0 0
5 1 1 1
6 1 0 0
7 1 0 1 
1 0 1 0
```

Then create a key for each element describing the differents sets it is in and register this element in a map.

For instance if we consider the key creation function as something like this:

```
int keyFunction(bool Xa, bool Xb, bool Xc) {
  int key =0;
  if (Xa) {key+=4;}
  if (Xb) {key+=2;}
  if (Xc) {key+=1;}
  return key;
}
```

We can then create the map:

```
Key ElementsQueue
0   []
1   []
2   [1]
3   []
4   [2,6]
5   [7]
6   []
7   [5]
```

and return the elements of this map.

Comment: I'll try to put an implementation draft if this solution seems fine for you

Comment: How did you arrive at the key values as 4,2,1?

Comment: @aceBox We can consider the boolean list as the bits of a binary number. So [x,y,z] is x*2^2+y*2^1+z*2^0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100235/discussion-between-88877-and-acebox).